# Missing File - Unable to install alongside windows 8 or on own on Samsung Series 9 Ultrabook

Tags: dual-boot, samsung

I currently have a Samsung Series 9 Ultrabook 128GB SSD and 8GB of ram. I have been trying to install Ubuntu to run alongside windows but I cannot get it to work properly. I tried disabling secure boot, fast BIOS mode, and switched to CSM OS mode.

However, when I try to reboot and then head to OS selection, I select Ubuntu and get an error saying that it cannot run because there is a file missing.

I downloaded Ubuntu straight from the website so i am completely unsure of what file is missing. If anyone else has this trouble and has fixed it or if anyone has a clue please help.

---

Yes, windows 8 came pre-installed on the samsung laptop. I am trying to install through wubi.exe.

Comment: How are you installing Ubuntu? via a DVD?

Comment: First, you have Windows installed already? Second, did you install via Wubi.exe or a Ubuntu Boot CD/DVD?

Comment: these are 2 good links http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2144682 http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2097690 have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use Wubi on Windows 8.

Wubi does not support Windows 8.  The lack of support for Windows 8 with Wubi is one of the reasons Wubi support was dropped from 12.10, 13.04, and onwards.

Wubi will not work with Windows 8.